# Google Earth Engine: command not found

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm following the tutorial [listed here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install_manual) to install the Python API for Google Earth Engine. I successfully installed all the packages-- although I installed them into /home/alelliot/install, not /usr/local, so that I wouldn't have to use sudo.

I am at the "Setting Up Authentication Credentials" step, but now I'm getting this error:

```
alelliot@precisionm6600c:~/install$ earthengine authenticate
earthengine: command not found
```

I can clearly see that the earthengine package has been correctly installed, so I don't know why I'm getting this error (the directory below is truncated for clarity):

```
alelliot@precisionm6600c:~/install$ ls -l
[...]
drwxrwxr-x  2 alelliot mtriuser   4096 Jul 26 13:12 cryptography-2.0.dist-info
-rwxrwxr-x  1 alelliot mtriuser    339 Jul 27 04:33 earthengine
drwxrwxr-x  2 alelliot mtriuser   4096 Jul 26 13:12 earthengine_api-0.1.119.dist-info
-rw-rw-r--  1 alelliot mtriuser    126 Jul 26 13:10 easy_install.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 alelliot mtriuser    315 Jul 26 13:10 easy_install.pyc
drwxrwxr-x  4 alelliot mtriuser   4096 Jul 26 13:12 ee
[...]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And the "~/install" directory is on your path?

Comment: I thought it was, but apparently not. Using `export PATH=$PATH:~/install` seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you!